# Apache's mod_cache not caching FCGI PHP output

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi, mod-cache

I have a very simple PHP script to test my mod_cache setup. However, it's not working -- I can tell by both the 5 second delay when waiting for the page to load as well as the date printed.

```
<?php

        ob_start();

        header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime(__FILE__)).' GMT', true, 200);                               
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public',true);
        header('Pragma: Public',true);
        header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('now + 10 years')) . ' GMT',true);
        header("Vary: Accept-Encoding");
        header("Content-Type: {$mime}",true);

        sleep(5);

        echo "test: ".date('n/d/y g:i:s A'); 

        header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
        ob_end_flush();
```

This same script works just fine with mod_php. Can mod_fastcgi content not be cached? Do I need to change the headers in order to get the content to be cacheable? Suggestions welcome.

EDIT: Adding relevant apache config:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

FastCgiConfig -idle-timeout 20 -maxClassProcesses 1

AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /cgi-bin/php.fcgi

<Location "/cgi-bin/php.fcgi">
   Options ExecCGI
   SetHandler fastcgi-script
</Location>

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|bmp|ico)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
</FilesMatch>

CacheEnable disk /
CacheRoot /var/www/cache
CacheDirLevels 3
CacheDirLength 1
CacheDefaultExpire 10
CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
```

And output of `GET` showing headers:

```
[jnet@workingman public_html]$ time GET -Sed http://localhost/cachetest.php
GET http://localhost/cachetest.php --> 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2009 21:40:17 GMT
Pragma: Public
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 25
Content-Type: 
Expires: Sun, 13 Oct 2019 21:40:17 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Oct 2009 12:40:57 GMT
Client-Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2009 21:40:22 GMT
Client-Peer: 72.52.238.75:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11


real    0m6.261s
user    0m0.198s
sys     0m0.823s
```

Comment: Can you add your Apache configuration and the output of "GET -Sed http://your.server/your.script.php?

Comment: "GET -Sed http://your.server/your.script.php", I mean.

Comment: Okay, so http:// is trimmed out :~)

Comment: @markdrayton: Added. let me know if you need more of httpd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bug 48364](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48364) on Apache's bugzilla may eventually help with this, although as of now it doesn't.

Comment: Looks like exactly my issue, thanks! In the meantime I solved it by having my server be a caching proxy to itself for PHP scripts. A bit slower perhaps but the caching works then.